# Getting error while mounting EFS to ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I want to mount EFS to ECS Farget. But I'm continuously getting below error:

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:71: ...
Command ["df -h && while true; do echo \\\"RUNNING\\\"; done"]
```

I followed article : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/

I have given access in EFS Security Group (InBound rule) to Security group for ECS for port 2049.  ECS Container has simple nginx container running on port 80 so port 80 accessible on internet.

In task definition I have also Add volume i have created and same has been referred in container definition.

As per article I did all things but still getting an error.

Can you please help what can be wrong here? May be I'm missing some configuration

Comment: Is there more in the error message in place of `...` at the end?

Comment: No, its just continuation and then Command ["df -h && while true; do echo \\\"RUNNING\\\"; done"]